# Auth0 get user email after authorization

Tags: auth0

I have an application and an api, in terms of auth0, an static frontend and a expressjs backend, in production both are working. I setup Auth0 and users are able to login with Google accounts.

I couldn't get the user's email. I will try to summarize the lines of code that matters

```
const jwt = require('express-jwt');
const jwks = require('jwks-rsa');
const jwtAuthz = require('express-jwt-authz');

let jwtCheck = jwt({
  secret: jwks.expressJwtSecret({
    cache: true,
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
    jwksUri: `https://myapp-01.us.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json`
  }),
  audience: `https://api.myapp.com`,
  issuer: `https://myapp-01.us.auth0.com/`,
  algorithms: ['RS256']
});

const checkClientScopes = jwtAuthz(['openid', 'profile', 'email'], { checkAllScopes: true });

app.use('/users', jwtCheck, checkClientScopes, (req, res) => {
  console.log('*** req.user *** ', req.user)
  res.send({ user: req.user })
})
```

I have been trying to get the user email, I installed, and then I removed the library `express-openid-connect`. My guess is I missed an small piece of code that I am missing, or a library I didn't installed

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using `express-jwt` and `jwks-rsa`

I was able to create a function to retrieve the user data, but I need to add `axios` library to request the `/userinfo`, after

This is the function I created

```
const jwtUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  const response = await axios.get(req.user.aud[1], { headers: { 'Authorization': req.headers.authorization } });
  req.user = response.data;
  next()
};
```

Then I am able to get the user data

```
app.use('/userdata', jwtCheck, jwtUser, (req, res) => {
  console.log('user: ', req.user);
  res.send(JSON.stringify(req.user));
})
```

Hopefully it will be useful for someone else